# Использование сохранённой сессии Telegram через Telethon на Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Вопрос, то в общем простой, как переиспользовать сессию, которая и так уже сохранена в текущей директории проекта? 
Согласно тутору всё просто, если имя сессии не менялось, то запрос кода вы больше не будете получать, однако я при каждом подключении получаю этот запрос и уже один раз получил `FloodWaitError`
Этот код уже я выполнял не раз, и у меня уже сформировался файл mtproxy.session в директории с проектом. Но почему-то он его не переиспользует(

Вот код:

```py
api_id = 8XXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXX'
DC1_ip = '149.154.167.40'
DC_port = 443
# https://t.me/proxy?server=Ritmseda.online&port=50&ref_secret-share=@mtprotoproxies&secret=5421e99c282e878cea1839bc1a252971
proxy_ip = 'proxy.digitalresistance.dog'
proxy_port = 443
secret = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
proxy = (proxy_ip, proxy_port, secret)
client = TelegramClient('mtproxy', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(proxy_ip, proxy_port, secret),
                        connection=connection.tcpmtproxy.ConnectionTcpMTProxy)
client.session.set_dc(1, DC1_ip, DC_port)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='PCXDE'))
async def normal_handler(event):
    print(event.message)
    print(event.message.to_dict()['message'])
    print(event.message.to_dict()['media'])
    # await client.download_media(event.message)
    print('Download done! {}'.f(await client.download_media(event.message)))


client.start()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
   print('Not authorized!')
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Включил дэбаг получил INFO ```INFO:telethon.client.updates:Failed to get current state: AuthKeyUnregisteredError('The key is not registered in the system (caused by GetStateRequest)')
```

Comment: вы пробовали это на другом прокси? или просто без прокси (через VPN)?

Comment: Как с вами связаться ?
по сессии #257513005 (старый способ)

Answer (score 0):

Во всём была виной эта строка:

```
client.session.set_dc(1, DC1_ip, DC_port)
```

Почему-то при указании конкретного DataCenter ключ сбрасывался.
Стоило убрать эту строку, так всё стало хорошо.